# Windows Phone in Microsoft Expression Blend 4

Tags: c#, windows-phone, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

Why do not I have a "Windows Phone" tab when I want to create a project in Microsoft Expression Blend 4?

[screenshot №1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUm9o.jpg) - What I want to have when I create a project in Expression Blend 4.

[screenshot №2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqMeg.jpg) - What I have when create new project in my Expression Blend 4.

Comment: Do you have Windows Phone SDK installed?

Comment: @Martin Zikmund So I just need to download and installed Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: I think it should be sufficient